# Passing values of different types to shader

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am using GLEW32 with GLFW and write code on C++. I have encountered some problems passing values to shader. I have successfully passed `vec2, uvec3` etc. Now I want to pass multiple values for each vertex:

1. `uvec2` (or `vec2` - not very important) - X and Y position;
2. `uvec4` - RGBA color. I can also use `int` to decode RGBA from int32, but `uvec4` would be more convinient :)

But there's another problem: I can set different attributes types using `glVertexAttribIPointer()` or `glVertexAttribPointer()`:

```
glVertexAttribIPointer(0, 2, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, ...);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribIPointer(1, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ...);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
```

But I cannot pass values of different types to `glBufferData()`:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(array), array, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW); // Just one array!!!
```

I tried to do this using uniforms, but the code was tooo bulky and inefficient that I gave it up. Are there any ways to do such a manipulations "properly"?

Comment: *"But I cannot pass values of different types to glBufferData():"* - Of course you can. The argument to `glBufferData` is just a buffer of a certain size, but the buffer has no type.

Comment: Do you mean I can pass bytes of needed information encoded to single bytes?

Comment: What do you mean by “encoded to single bytes”? Everything is bytes

Comment: For example, I have 2 floats that occupie 4 bytes each and 4 uchars that occupie 1 byte each (12 bytes in total). I could somehow turn all the data into bytes and pass it. Or I can use union to make values occupie the same memory addresses. Or did I understand you wrong?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in [Kai Burjack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8623159/kai-burjack)'s comment. I made a structure to keep data and send it. The code is:

```
struct dataToSend
{
    GLushort x, y;
    GLubyte r, g, b, a;
}
...
glVertexAttribIPointer(0, 2, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, sizeof(dataToSend), (GLvoid *) 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribIPointer(1, 4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, sizeof(dataToSend), (GLvoid *) (2 * sizeof(GLushort)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
...
            // (pixels) x      y       r    g    b    a
dataToSend data [4] = {{width, height, 255, 255, 0,   255},  // Corner 1 (Up-Right)
                       {width, 0,      255, 0,   255, 255},  // Corner 2 (Down-Right)
                       {0,     0,      0,   255, 0,   0},    // Corner 3 (Down-Left)
                       {0,     height, 0,   255, 255, 255}}; // Corner 4 (Up-Left)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data), (GLvoid *) data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
```

That was kinda weird experience to use GLvoid and point to a structure instead of array but this lets one to pass almost any data to shaders. The result image is here:
[Rendered image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu0ms.png)